# No year is shown in the lists of All Actions

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, profile-page

I can't see this being asked before, although maybe I haven't searched enough.

If I go to my profile, click on **All Actions** and then the **Comments** tab, there is a long list (and multiple pages) of my past comments shown.

> [image: Top of comments list]

However, no year information is shown, only the month - even for comments posted over a year ago.

> [image: Bottom of comments list]

This is confusing, as it makes one wonder if the date (month/day) refers to *this* year. The presentation is the same, whether the same month and day of the comment is from *this* year or *last* year, or three years ago.

I was trying to locate an old comment, but was continually losing track of what year I was currently looking at, and had to click on random comments in the list to see to which year, that particular part of the comment list, pertained.

It would be nice to have the year added, or maybe "*n* years ago" (although this is not as good as having the actual year displayed.

This issue affects the Comments, Suggestions, Reviews, Revisions, Badges - in fact all of the tabs under **All Actions**.

It does not affect Reputation tab, maybe that sort of display could be used?

> [image: Reputation]

Comment: Hover over the date and the year is displayed as a tooltip.

Comment: Yes it's in a tooltip, but the "questions" and "answers" top-level tabs show years when the post is more than a year old (same algorithm as for the posts themselves), so it'd be nice if we could get that for the activity history too.

Comment: @MonicaCellio - Yes, that would be more appropriate than the reputation format. The problem with tooltips, it that one has to keep on reaching for the mouse, and hence more RSI

Comment: This would have made getting the [this is fine](https://winterbash2017.stackexchange.com/this-is-fine) hat a tad easier